# How to move/animate text values in navbar when I toggle the sidebar

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap

How do I flex the contents of my navbar when I toggle the sidebar on/off in ReactJS? In my current website my sidebar overlaps the navbar so when I toggle it on, more than half of the title gets covered ([sample1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phhJo.png), [sample2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjN3A.png))

This is my `Navbar.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {Navbar, Container} from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import './styles/styles.css';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import { SidebarItem } from './SidebarItem';

export default function Navubaru({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth()
    const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

    const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);
    return (
        <div>
            
    <Navbar bg="myColor" variant="dark">
    <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
              <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
        </Link>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
            <ul className='nav-menu-items' onClick={showSidebar}>
              <li className='navbar-toggle'>
                <Link to='#' className='menu-bars'>
                  <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
                </Link>
              </li>
              {SidebarItem.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                    <Link to={item.path}>
                      {item.icon}
                      <span>{item.title}</span>
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </ul>
          </nav>
        
    
    
    </IconContext.Provider>
    <Container>
    
    <Navbar.Brand href="/">Welcome to my Website</Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle />
    <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
      <Navbar.Text>
        Signed in as: <a href="/">{currentUser && currentUser.email}</a>
      </Navbar.Text>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Container>
    </Navbar>
    </div>
    )
}
```

I'd also like to flex/minimize the size of the main page when I toggle the sidebar if there's not much difference in the methods of doing it. I'd appreciate any help and thoughts given. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set padding-left to the navbar's wrapper when sidebar is open and remove it when the sidebar close.

Here is an example [navbar](https://codesandbox.io/s/navbar-0rq4l?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: This worked nicely especially when I added a transition for it too. Thank you!